# Best way to store Array from checkbox in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Lease model that has a constant of "utilities" options

model

```
class Lease
    def self.utilities_options
        ["Gas", "Electric", "Trash", "Water"]
    end
end
```

form

```
 <% Lease.utilities_options.each do |option| %>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <%= check_box_tag "lease[utilities][]", option %>
      <%= f.label option %>
    </div>  
  <% end %>
```

What is the best way to convert the array of selected items into a string `params[:lease]["utilities"].join(",")` and then when the form is displayed for editing, to reselect those options?

Comment: Should `lease_info[utilities][]` be `lease[utilities][]`?

Comment: @usmanali The typo has been fixed.

Comment: One more question. What field are you using to store utilities in model?

Comment: @usmanali Right now I am using a string field. I currently have this line of code before I call update_attributes. ```params[:lease]["utilities"] = params[:lease]["utilities"].join(",") if params[:lease]["utilities"]``` This works to turn the array into a string, but this particular form is referenced and edited alot, I really need a way to take that string and display those utilities as selected on the form.

Comment: What DBMS you are using ?